# How to disable List evaluation in Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA) debugger

Tags: java, debugging, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm trying to debug a `java.util.List` implementation using `Android Studio` and the debugger is getting in the way (sic). Specifically, in the debug view the IDE attempts to evaluate the size and elements of my List well before I've hit the breakpoints I've place there in my List. Is there a way to disable this?

That's it in a nutshell, but for more context, my Lists are lazily loaded and are often just views onto other underlying lists. So here's a trivial example:

```
public class BrokenList extends java.util.AbstractList<Double> {
@Override
public Double get(int location) {
    return 1 / Math.sin(50 - location);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return 100;
}
}
```

The above blows up at index (location) 50. Attempting to see this in debug view would be a pain.

Comment: Android Studio is nothing to do with Eclipse

Comment: Agreed. My bad. Title and tags updated. Thanks